# SELECT query that depends on two other tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to make a SELECT query that depends on two other tables

table 1: **tbcategories**

```
id      name   
--      ----
1       category1
2       category2
3       category3
```

table 2: **tbgroups**

```
id      category    name   
--      --------    ----
1       1           group1
2       1           group2
3       2           group3
```

table 3: **tbchilds**

```
id      group       name   
--      -----       ----
1       group1      child1
2       group1      child2
3       group2      child3
4       group2      child4
5       group3      child5
```

What I need - The query syntax which gives me all the childs (tbchilds) that their "group" is on specific category.
For example: **give me all the childs that "under" category1** = the output will be:

```
child1
child2
child3
child4
```

10X

Comment: Have you checked for join syntax in query ?

Comment: @Yinon Nadav review posted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052236/select-query-that-depends-on-two-other-tables/25052311#25052311 and refer the link about joining conditions http://tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Best example for PHP MySQL joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

**Try**

```
SELECT ch.name FROM tbchilds ch 
  JOIN tbgroups gr ON ch.group=gr.name 
  JOIN tbcategories cat ON cat.id=gr.category 
WHERE cat.name='category1';
```

Comment: @Yinon Nadav review above posted answer and refer the link about joining conditions

Comment: hi 10X - I've tried it and it shows me one rows only not all of the results

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbcategories a
INNER JOIN 
        tbgroups b
    ON
        a.id = b.category
JOIN
        tbchilds t3
    ON
        t2.name = t3.group
WHERE
    t1.name ='category1'
```

Answer (score 0):

this untested query should get you the expected result:

```
select t3.name from tbcategories t1 join tbgroups t2 on t1.id = t2.category   join tbchilds t3 on t2.name=t3.`group` where t1.name ='category1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:

```
SELECT C.name
FROM tbcategories A 
INNER JOIN tbgroups B
ON A.id = B.category
INNER JOIN tbchilds C
ON B.name = C.group
WHERE A.name = 'CATEGORY1';
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Query -

```
SELECT CH.name FROM tbgroups AS G

INNER JOIN tbchilds AS CH ON CH.group = G.id

INNER JOIN tbcategories AS C ON C.id = G.category

WHERE C.id = <CategoryID>;
```